# What is this syntax: "ACGT"[(int)qrand() % 4]

Tags: c++, qt

I'm looking at a Qt specific C++ [solution](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtcore-semaphores-example.html) for the typical producer/consumer problem.  Here's the code for the producer:

```
class Producer : public QThread
{
public:
    void run()
    {
        qsrand(QTime(0,0,0).secsTo(QTime::currentTime()));
        for (int i = 0; i < DataSize; ++i) {
            freeBytes.acquire();                                 // (1)
            buffer[i % BufferSize] = "ACGT"[(int)qrand() % 4];   // (2)
            usedBytes.release();
        }
    }
};
```

I am not able to understand the second line in the `for` loop viz. `"ACGT"[*]` syntax. What does it do exactly? Is this Qt specific or is this C++ syntax I'm not aware of?

PS: Full source code [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtcore-semaphores-semaphores-cpp.html)

Comment: Does it help you understand if I tell you that `"ACGT"` is a `char const(&)[5]` ?

Comment: It's the same as `((int)qrand() % 4)["ACGT"]`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I was *so* about to mention that as well. They could have made it considerably more obtuse by using that very expression (just to keep the reader interested =P).

Comment: @KerrekSB yeah right. Play on. lol.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yup. It does clear the clouds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It generates a random characted from: A, C, G, T.

Literal `"ACGT"` is an array of type `char const [5]` then `[(int)qrand() % 4]` is a random index in a range from 0 to 3 including.

Answer (score 4):

> "ACGT"[*] syntax. What does it do exactly?

`qrand() % 4` is a random number between 0 and 3. That random number is used as an index into the string `"ACGT`". So the whole expression yields a random character A, C, G or T with equal probability.